# How to display the date in a MonthCalendar control?

Tags: vb.net

How can I type a date in a TextBox and display that date in MonthCalendar? I can pick a date in MonthCalendar and display in the TextBox but I can't do with my problem.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Blt_search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Blt_search.Click  'ButtonSearchDate'
    tbx_finddate.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a DateTimePicker control (it supports custom formats), so you have a textbox-like input control and the MonthCalendar control all-in-one (and avoid input validation).

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the answer , i will find it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do reverse the process (from TextBox to MonthCalendar instead of the other way around). In which case, you need to parse the string in the TextBox in order to convert it to a Date datatype.

Assuming you want to use the same format, you may try something like this:

```
Dim inputDate As Date
If Date.TryParseExact(tbx_finddate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                      Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, inputDate) Then
    MonthCalendar1.SetDate(inputDate)
End If
```

Comment: Thank for the answer , i just want display the date i want in MonthCalendar when i type the date in Textbox.

Comment: @ĐứcThắng That's what the code in my answer does. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried your code , it's hard to descripe the result  . It's work when the year is 2020 , but if the year is 2019,2018,2017.... the MonthCalendar will display the date i want and include 17th or 16th with same month and year. I think you need to check because it's hard to say.

Comment: @ĐứcThắng I've updated the answer. Please check now.

Comment: tks a lot  it's work , i thought i will stay up all night today for this :D .